# starup file changes in Asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am Upgrading .Net core web api solution  2.2 to 3.1
I have question what should i use in statrup.cs file for 3.1

// currently i am using this
public Startup(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env)

public Startup(Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env)

Answer (score 0):

> I am Upgrading .Net core web api solution 2.2 to 3.1 I have question what should i use in statrup.cs file for 3.1

If you create a new ASP.NET Core 3.1 API project using [the API template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-web-project-1), you would find it uses below `Startup` class.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Compare it with old one, you can find the following changes:

- `services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)` is changed to `services.AddControllers()`
- `IHostingEnvironment` is obsolete, and it uses `IWebHostEnvironment` now
- `app.UseEndpoints`, endpoint routing is used

Comment: But My startup file is initially code is    public Startup(Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
              .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
              .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
              .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            this.Configuration = builder.Build(); ;
        }

Comment: public Startup(Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
              .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
              .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
              .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            this.Configuration = builder.Build(); ;
        }

Comment: To configures the configuration provider(s), you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#json-configuration-provider